# Error when trying to load JRuby script

Tags: java, class, methods, jruby

Here i am trying to load my Jruby script into my java code but am getting long error that i realy don't know what it means,

**The player.rb file is in the same folder as the TEST.java is.**

Here is the error am getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .player.rb (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:117)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1195)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1275)
at test.TEST.<init>(TEST.java:29)
at test.TEST.main(TEST.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.ParseFailedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .player.rb (The system cannot find the file specified)
at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:143)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1195)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1275)
at test.TEST.<init>(TEST.java:29)
at test.TEST.main(TEST.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .player.rb (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:117)
... 4 more
```

Java Result: 1

Here is my Java code:

```
import org.jruby.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.jruby.embed.PathType;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;

public class TEST {
    private final static String jrubyhome = "C:/jruby-1.6.3";
    private final String filename = "player.rb";

    private TEST() {
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        List<String> loadPaths = new ArrayList();
        loadPaths.add(jrubyhome);
        // JRuby 1.5.x
        container.setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
        // JRuby 1.4.0
        //container.getProvider().setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
        container.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE, filename);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TEST();
    }
}
```

And here is my Ruby code:

```
def numberMethod
  number = 3
return number
end

puts numberMethod
puts "Test, test!"
```

The new error i got now:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Oskar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TEST\src\test (Access is denied)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:79)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:117)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1195)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1275)
>       at test.TEST.(TEST.java:29)
>       at test.TEST.main(TEST.java:33)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.ParseFailedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Oskar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TEST\src\test (Access is denied)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:143)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1195)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1275)
>       at test.TEST.(TEST.java:29)
>       at test.TEST.main(TEST.java:33)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Oskar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TEST\src\test (Access is denied)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:79)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:117)
>       ... 4 more
>   Java Result: 1

The new java code:

```
    import org.jruby.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.jruby.embed.PathType;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;

public class TEST {
    private final static String jrubyhome = "C:/jruby-1.6.3";
    private final String filename = "C:/Users/Oskar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TEST/src/test/player.rb";

    private TEST() {
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        List<String> loadPaths = new ArrayList();
        loadPaths.add(jrubyhome);
        // JRuby 1.5.x
        container.setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
        // JRuby 1.4.0
        //container.getProvider().setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
        container.runScriptlet(PathType.RELATIVE, filename);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TEST();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the `PathType.ABSOLUTE` constant is the culprit. Change that (e.g. to `PathType.RELATIVE`) or provide the full path to your `test.rb` file.

Comment: Which solution did you try? How do you run your program?

Comment: Well then, try to paste at least significant portions of the new errors.

Comment: Alright i will paste the new error but not in the comment it will be in the question post since its too bit for posting it in a comment.. It will be on the bottom there.